# "/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf" similar file not found in windows

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I know ubuntu and windows have different structure for xampp. I tried to find "/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf" this file in windows but not found anywhere. I am trying to speeding up phpmyadmin by using [this tutorial](http://tfountain.co.uk/blog/2010/7/29/speeding-up-phpmyadmin). Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have install the wamp in C: then you can find the *phpmyadmin.conf* file in **C:\wamp\alias**  folder